# Plotting a dynamical system code fix needed!

Tags: manipulate, code-review

So I'm trying to plot a system of differential equations separately and look at how their solutions behave:

$$\dot{x}_{1} = x_{1} (K_{1} - x_{1}) + \epsilon (x_{2} - x_{1})$$  $$\dot{x}_{2} = x_{2} (K_{2} - x_{2}) + \epsilon (x_{1} - x_{2})$$

where $K_{1}$ and $K_{2}$ are arbitrary constants along with $\epsilon$.
Here is the code in mathematica that I've attempted to create.  Can anyone see what's wrong with this code?

```
Manipulate[
     (sol = NDSolve[{x'[t] == 
          x[t] * (α - x[t]) + ϵ*(y[t] - x[t]), 
         y'[t] ==  y[t] * (β - y[t]) + ϵ*(x[t] - y[t]), 
         x[0] == 0.001, y[0] ==  0.001}, x[t], y[t], {t, 0, 1000}];
      Plot[Evaluate[x[t], y[t] /. sol], {t, 0, 1000}, 
       PlotRange -> {0, 10}]), {{α, 0.01}, 0, 
      10}, {{β, 0.01}, 0, 8}, {{ϵ, 1}, 0, 10}]
```

Comment: First thing to do, before going to a large forum, is try to debug individual pieces. For this purpose, start with the `NDSolve`, and set the parameters to specific values e.g. the initial values in teh `Manipulate`.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
Γ = ParametricNDSolveValue[{
    x'[t] == x[t]*(α - x[t]) + ϵ*(y[t] - x[t]),
    y'[t] == y[t]*(β - y[t]) + ϵ*(x[t] - y[t]), 
    x[0] == 0.001, y[0] == 0.001},
   {x[t], y[t]}, {t, 0, 1000},
   {α, β, ϵ}
   ];

Manipulate[
 With[{γ = Γ[α, β, ϵ]},
  ParametricPlot[γ, {t, 0, 1000}, PlotRange -> {0, 10}]
  ],
 {{α, 0.01}, 0, 10}, {{β, 0.01}, 0, 8}, {{ϵ, 1}, 0, 10}
 ]
```